# Multiresolution modifier split face in half

Tags: modeling

I am a blender beginner and have been working on a Youtube project. I wanted to use a multiresolution modifier but when I applied it, it suddenly split my project's face in half! Please help! Images are placed below. [image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I have managed to finish my project!

Answer (score 1):

Two checks:

1. Put the Mirror modifier on the top of other modifiers, a good sequence of using modifiers as example: Mirror -> Bevel -> Sub Division.
2. If the mirror modifier is on the top, make sure the clipping option is on, then move the vertices towards the middle, they will automatically merge.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping but unconnected vertices. You should try to merge the vertices in edit mode before subdividing: [image]